# array_intersect() not working anymore?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

i had 2 array;

```
$friends = array();
$idpens = array();
```

then i get friend id from facebook for $friends

```
$result = $this->facebook->api("/me/friends");
        foreach($result['data'] as $index => $friend){
               $friends[] = $friend['id'];
            }
```

and get id in database

```
$idpencipi=$this->persion->getid();
        foreach($idpencipi as $index => $idpen){
               $idpens[] = $idpen['fb_id'];
            }
```

Print:

```
print_r($friends): Array (
[0] => 1009167810
[1] => 106309886180996
[2] => 1677624156
[3] => 1818586059
[4] =>100004421164127)


print_r($idpens): Array (
[0] => 100004421164127
[1] => 106309886180996
[2] => 2345679543234 )
```

but when i use array_intersect()

```
print_r(array_intersect($idpens,$friends));
```

output:

```
Array()
```

What can i do?

Comment: [_Cannot Reproduce_](https://eval.in/138094)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this code.Its working fine.
I think somewhere one of your array getting override and that's why its not able to find common element.

Note: Please trim input data. It may be because of unwanted spaces.

Please double check this or post your whole script code.

Comment: if you find this answer useful then dont forget to accept or rate it up